# ember.js and webservice / boolean false taken as an empty field

Tags: web-services, checkbox, ember.js, is-empty

in my ember app I have a 'isPossible' checkbox. When it's checked, value is set to 'true' and everything works fine with my web service, but when it's left unchecked - I get 'false' value

```
{"myobject":{(...),"isPossible":false}}
```

which is completely ignored and I get an error:

```
"isPossible":{"isEmpty":"Value is required and can\u0027t be empty"}
```

Any hints on what should I change to simply see it as anything other than an empty value?

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying when the checkbox is unchecked, your isPossible property has a value of null, when you want it to have a value of false?

Comment: When it's unchecked, it gets a value 'false', but when being sent to a web service, I get a null error. Should I take into consideration that the problem might be on server's side instead of ember's?

Answer (score 0):

Are you serializing to JSON properly?  Make sure your JSON is valid using a tool like http://jsonlint.com/.